# After resolving all conflicts in rebasing my branch, I did "git rebase --continue" and I got "No rebase in progress?" . What should I do next?

Tags: git, github, rebase

I am trying to rebase my branch with my develop branch. In the process of resolving conflicts and 
`git rebase --continue`
I ended up to a point where I am done resolving everything and I did 
`git rebase --continue` again

```
pragyagoel$ git rebase --continue
No rebase in progress?
pragyagoel$
```

On git status it gives me following:

```
pragyagoel$ git status
On branch Pragya_Develop_2
Your branch and 'origin/Pragya_Develop_2' have diverged,
and have 64 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
pragyagoel$
```

Not sure what I am supposed to do next as its as I have no place to response to "No rebase in progress?". It directly goes to new command line.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from `git-gui` so we can visualise the branches?

Comment: @Dai no I cant share screenshot.. it has sensitive data.. I renamed the branch and project name to keep it safe to ask the question here

Comment: @pragya.go did you have any luck solving your problem yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your rebase completed successfully.

If you run

```
git log --graph --decorate Pragya_Develop_2 origin/Pragya_Develop_2
```

it should show you your rebased commits in branch `Pragya_Develop_2`, which have diverged from `origin/Pragya_Develop_2` precisely because you've done the rebase.

If you are happy with the result and want to update the branch on `origin` with the rebased one, you can now do `git push -f`.

Caveat: there are a lot of good reasons to avoid pushing the results of a rebase, but to use a merge instead. I recommend reading up on that (google "git rebase vs merge" to find dozens of pages on the topic), but here I am answering your question as asked, assuming that rebase really is what you want to do.